Display users data from node js to react
I want to display in a page the name, email of my user logged in
I connect the front and the back together, in my index.js (back) I did that :
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require("cors");
const corsOption = {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"]
}

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors(corsOption));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({fruits : ["apple", "Orange", "Kiwi"]});  
});

Then in my folder front to display this fruits collections I set up the main.jsx :
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css';



createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)


And in my App.jsx :
import './index.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  const fetchApi = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api");
      setArray(response.data.fruits);
      console.log(response.data.fruits);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération des données : ", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((fruit, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{fruit}</p>
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


it does actually work in my localhost, but I would create a file user.jsx to display the informations of them, but I don't understand where and how to import them if I create a folder Users into my src and try to import it from main.jsx everything crash

So, what is the question?

Display users data from node js to react, I mean the way that I'm trying doesn't work..

Hi, Thank you for the post. Please also include "the way you are trying" to make it as a reproducible one. The community will certainly help. In other words, please review the post as if the same question I was asking you , and assume you are the one trying to answer. Is there anything to be added to make it much possible as an answerable one.

Are you trying to display your fetched data in a component?
user.jsx
 const User = ({ fruit }) => {
  return <div>{fruit} in user.jsx</div>;
};

export default User;

App.jsx
import './index.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import User from "./user";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  const fetchApi = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api");
      setArray(response.data.fruits);
      console.log(response.data.fruits);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération des données : ", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((fruit, index) => (
        <User key={index} fruit={fruit}></User>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

